# Getting From, SentOnBehalfOfName and Account name from MailItem Object (Outlook Shared Addins)

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, mailitem, shared-addin

I am using Vs2010 -> Extensibility->Shared Add-in 
I have added a event handler to my ItemSend

```
applicationObject.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(applicationObject_ItemSend);  

void applicationObject_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if(Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (mailItem != null)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Sender's Email Address "+mailItem.SenderEmailAddress);
           MessageBox.Show("Sender's Email Address "+mailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName); 
          MessageBox.Show("Sender's Email Address "+mailItem.SendUsingAccount);
        }
    }
}
```

`mailItem.SenderEmailAddress,mailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` and `mailItem.SendUsingAccount`
I am geting all of this property null

Please can you anyone help me out 
I want to get From, `SentOnBehalfOfName` and Account name from with the email was sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sender related properties are set only after the message is actually sent and moved to the Sent Items folder. You might want to use the Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Can i get which Account's email address and Account Name  I am sending the email in ItemSend only

Comment: Yes, but it might be null unless it was explicitly specified.

Comment: Ok I got the work around i used mailItem.SendUsingAccount; Display Name and Resolved the smtpAddress too

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to do that - each Account object exposes the Account.CurrentUser property (returns the Recipient object).

Answer (score 0):

This is the Code i have used

```
    public Outlook.MAPIFolder sentFolder = null;
    public Outlook.Items itmsSentFolder = null;
    sentFolder = applicationObject.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    itmsSentFolder = sentFolder.Items;
    itmsSentFolder.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(itmsSentFolder_ItemAdd); 
void itmsSentFolder_ItemAdd(object Item)
        {

                if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (mailItem != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Sender's Email Address " + mailItem.SenderEmailAddress);
                        MessageBox.Show("Sent On Behalf Of Name " + mailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName);
                        Outlook.Account ac = (Outlook.Account)mailItem.SendUsingAccount;
                        if(ac != null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Sender's Account Name " + ac.SmtpAddress);
                        }

                    }

            }
        }
```

Thanks for the  idea Dmitry Streblechenko